# debian - wifi option not available in connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

It's only some hours since I have installed Debian 10 with KDE on my hp bs-145tu laptop. I have installed `firmware-realtek` from apt and I still can't see any wifi option at all. I have been able to use ethernet though. How do I enable and use wifi?

I am using Debian 10.9 with KDE on intel cpu with realtek wlan device.

here's what `lspci` returns:

```
neevan@nebian:~$ lspci
...
...
...
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
```

see the screenshots  here:
[image]
[image]

### EDIT 1:

```
neevan@nebian:~$ sudo lspci -k
...
...
...
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
neevan@nebian:~$ sudo ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:7a:10:67:8b:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
neevan@nebian:~$ nmcli dev
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
eno1    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --  
neevan@nebian:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i wlan
[    3.266679] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

#### EDIT 2:

```
neevan@nebian:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
```

#### EDIT 3:

```
neevan@nebian:~$ uname -a
Linux nebian 5.10.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1~bpo10+1 (2021-03-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
neevan@nebian:~$ lspci -k
...
...
...
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        Kernel modules: rtw88_8723de
```

Comment: Can you run `sudo lspci -k`, find the Wi-Fi adapter in there, and check whether it has a driver bound to it? Can you run `dmesg` and try to find any messages related to the adapter or the driver or the firmware? Can you check whether `ip link` and `nmcli dev` show a device named "wlan0" or "wl(something)"?

Comment: Hmm, could you also run `lspci -nn` to get the vendor:model IDs of your Wi-Fi adapter?

Comment: please do check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your Wi-Fi adapter (PCI 10ec:d723) is handled by the "rtw88" driver, which was added in **Linux kernel 5.2**. However, Debian 10 (Buster) only comes with kernel 4.19 by default, so you will need to install a newer one (5.10) from the [backports](https://backports.debian.org/) repository. You will also need the updated firmware collection along with it.

After enabling backports, use:

```
apt install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64 firmware-realtek
```

Comment: i have enabled backports by adding `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free` to my "/etc/apt/sources.list" and ran the command you gave and installed those 2 and rebooted. after the restart i could neither see wifi enabled in bottom right panel nor could i see anything from `nmcli dev`

Comment: am i doing it right?

Comment: I think so -- have you checked the new kernel version via `uname -a` though? Does lspci -k now mention a driver?

Comment: check my edit now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dkms for your device with suitable driver version. You can find it from apt repo. Sometimes some motherboard needs special drivers.